# Is there a free High Performance Fortran (HPF) compiler for Windows?

Tags: windows, fortran, hpf

I have to do an assignment in HPF but I can't find a free compiler for Windows.

Comment: How come that you get an assignment in HPF? I thought that HPF was almost dead like UPC is.

Comment: I have to analyze various programming languages by solving the same problem in each language. For some of the parallelism aspects, the teacher suggested using Fortran, and in the specific HPF.

Comment: Well, would your teacher be fine with a different implementation? As stated, HPF [has not found widespread use](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1238844.1238851), despite its early pioneering of native, portable options for parallel computing. Fortran standards since 95 have (slowly as always) incorporated more and more of these, especially F2008. Unless you must use HPF or will in the future, you will probably find much better support for regular Fortan and OpenMP among both compilers and users.

Comment: What is your teacher / professor expecting you to use for a compiler? What are his recommendations? Do you have access to a machine on campus to do the work?

Comment: The teacher didn't say a thing about the compiler and the machines on campus don't have any compiler for fortran. Well, I think I'll try asking if using OpenMP is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this compile will support it, even tho its not on the description:

http://www.pgroup.com/products/pvf.htm

Maybe call them.

Comment: PVF is everything else but free.

Comment: Yet +1 since PGI provide a true HPF compiler. Apparently academics in USA and Germany can obtain limited-time free licences.

Answer (score 0):

No one yet mentioned the obvious... [MinGW with gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries). Free and pretty good.

[Intel Fortran](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-composer-xe/) is also free for non-commercial use (but it has to be really non-commercial - academic work doesn't count).

[G95](http://www.g95.org/) is the other major free / open source contender and could be worth a try - but I have only first hand had success with gfortran on windows (only because I never tried g95).

I'm still looking for a free Fortran compiler that can build 64 bit Matlab mex files on Windows. Intel Fortran works, gfortran can be made to work for 32 bit (with a bit of work) but I couldn't get gfortran working with 64 bit... If anyone knows one I would love to hear about it!

Comment: I'd say gfortran is a very good choice. The performance is mostly on-par with ifc. I recommend the MinGW-w64 TDM build, which is linked in the above site.

Comment: He is asking about "High Performance Fortran" compiler, not about "high performance" Fortran compiler. Neither `gfortran` nor Intel Fortran supports the full HPF specification, i.e. both are unable to create true distributed memory applications.

Comment: @Hristo But, both of them do support OpenMP and the elements of HPF that have been included in the Fortran standard. Intel also supports Fortran 2008 coarrays, in gfortran this is still experimental. If the emphasis is on free (non-commercial only for ifort) support for parallel programming, these are the best options, but this depends on the nature of the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

What about [this](http://www.pathscale.com/ekopath4-open-source-announcement). Their front page says that they've gone open source. You might check them out. There's also something called *ADAPTOR* out there, but I didn't find any useful live links for it. You might try to hunt that down. There may also be some open source projects on SourceForge, or some other repository.

CHEERS!

Comment: Ok, I thought we were a little more flexible than that. I know it says windows in the title, but you know what, a free solution is better than none. (BTW no thanks for the downvote of discouragement, whoever is responsible)

Comment: happy coder — I think that Stack Overflow lets you remove incorrect answers if you want the downvotes removed from your record! Remember that the voters are just trying to help future readers of the question know which answers will, in fact, lead them to Fortran for Windows. :)

Comment: I'll take the hit like a trooper. I disagree and stand by my answer as it provides something useful to the discussion. Thanks